# How to get all numbers from a file and input them into an array?

Tags: c, arrays

SO i can have a input file that can have either a space or a new line between each number within the file. An example of this could be:

```
input.txt
2 3 4 
4 3 2 3 
2 3 1 
5 4 3 2 
2 5 4 2
```

How would i parse through the file and grab all of the elements and place them inside an array. Currently I have the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define FILE_READ "input.txt"

int main()

{
FILE * filp;
int count = 1;
char c;
filp = fopen(FILE_READ, "r");
if(filp == NULL)
    printf("file not found\n");
while((c = fgetc(filp)) != EOF) {
    if(c == ' ')
        count++;
}
printf("numbers = %d\n", count);
return 0;
}
int myarray[count-1];
```

So how exactly would i push the numbers into the array at this point? I got the number of numbers in the file and created an array the size of the numbers. Now how exactly would i put the numbers into the array now?

Comment: Do you know about `fscanf()`?

Comment: @iharob dont you need to create an array before parsing through the file with fscanf? Im trying to make it so that the array has enough memory allocated to fit the exact number of numbers in the file

Comment: Yes, but you can count the values with `fscanf()` too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read and write from a file and create a matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40228175/how-to-read-and-write-from-a-file-and-create-a-matrix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple thing to do, just use `fscanf()` to count how many values and then use `malloc()` to allocate space for them. Then, use `fscanf()` again to read the values into the array.

This might seem like a lot of work, but allocating space for every value is more. One optimization that can be worth the effort would be to allocate an estimate size array and then grow the array in multiples of the initial estimate using `realloc()` when you run out of space. This way, you reduce the number of allocations and at the same time you only loop through the values (reading from the file which is also expensive only once).

This is the easiest way I think

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    FILE *file;
    int count;
    int value;
    file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
        return -1; // Error opening the file
    count = 0;
    while (fscanf(file, "%d", &value) == 1)
        count += 1;
    if (count > 0) {
        int *array;

        rewind(file);
        array = malloc(count * sizeof(*array));
        if (array == NULL) {
            fclose(file);
            return -1;
        }        
        count = 0;
        while (fscanf(file, "%d", &array[count]) == 1) {
            fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", array[count]);
            count += 1;
        }
        // Use the array now and then
        free(array);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: now if i wanted to separate them into different functions how would i do this? I would like to create a function with the following: